# JAVA Performance insights , refactoring existing code

Tags: java, jackson

I have a code like below, objective is to convert output of data layer to a generic data format so it can be used by other layers.

During my LT runs, i am observing this method consuming a considerable percentage of cpu time but still comparing to over all time it looks manageable.

But worried when it goes for stress testing it might blow up, so thinking for refactoring to remove object mapper usage and convert it by iteration.

I am not really a fan of converting a object to string and then back to another object structure. My belief is to avoid conversions(object-->String-->Object) and it will save time and memory is this is correct assumption?

```
ObjectMapper om = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
String listGridData = om.writeValueAsString(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode grid);
List<Map<String, Object>>   responseList = om.readValue(listGridData,
                    new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The ObjectMapper is something you want to re-use. There should be one instance per application. The object mapper is thread safe and there is no problem reusing it.

The second line from performance point of view is not an issue. With or without it is almost the same.

The performance of the third line depends on the complexity of the object to which you are parsing the String. The more complex it is the more references will be initialised and the more memory it will occupy. This will have effect on the performance.

How lightweight the object you are parsing to in the third step is vital together with the memory management  as well as the re-use of the ObjectMapper.